# OpenMP parallel calculating for loop indices

Tags: c++, openmp

My parallel programming class has the program below demonstrating how to use the parallel construct in OpenMP to calculate array bounds for each thread to be use in a for loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  int id = omp_get_thread_num();
  int p = omp_get_num_threads();
  int start = (N * id) / p;
  int end = (N * (id + 1)) / p;
  if (id == p - 1) end = N;
  for (i = start; i < end; i++)
  {
    A[i] = x * B[i];
  }
}
```

My question is, is the if statement (id == p - 1) necessary? From my understanding, if id = p - 1, then end will already be N, thus the if statement is not necessary. I asked in my class's Q&A board, but wasn't able to get a proper answer that I understood. Assumptions are: N is the size of array, x is just an int, id is between 0 and p - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are right**. Indeed, `(N * ((p - 1) + 1)) / p` is equivalent to
`(N * p) / p` assuming `p` is *strictly positive* (which is the case since the number of OpenMP thread is guaranteed to be at least 1). `(N * p) / p` is equivalent to `N` assuming there is no *overflow*. Such condition is often useful when the integer division cause some truncation but this is not the case here (it would be the case with something like `(N / p) * id`).

Note that this code is not very safe for large `N` because `sizeof(int)` is often 4 and the multiplication is likely to cause overflows (resulting in an *undefined behaviour*). This is especially true on machines with many cores like on supercomputer nodes. It is better to use the `size_t` type which is usually an unsigned 64-bit type meant to be able to represent the size of any object (for example the size of an array).